# Loading images from parse to image views

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing, ios4

I want to load images from parse as you can see in the screenshot.[image: my parse]

i am using this code to load the header image into my imageview.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AppOfTheDay"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"WDJpxs4PzH"
            block:^(PFObject *retreive, NSError *error) {
                {
    NSString *text = [retreive objectForKey:@"description"];
if (error) {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
            UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Connection Failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [error show];

        }
        else{
    PFFile *imageFile = [retreive objectForKey:@"header"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Something went wrong" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [error show];
    }
    else{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        _headerImage.image=image;
        _appDescription.text=text;
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

        }
        }];
        }
                }
            }];
```

My question is how can i similarly load my other three images into imageviews?

Answer (score 0):

implement lazy loading images. 
for example-NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
if ( queue == nil )
{
    queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
}
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * resp, NSData     *data, NSError *error) 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ 
                   {
                        if ( error == nil && data )
                        {
                            UIImage *urlImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                            thumbnail.image = urlImage;
                        }
                   });
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you alot,It will sort your problem with best loading speed

//yourclass.h

```
AsyncImageView *imageasy,*imageasy1, *imageasy2,imageasy3;
```

yourclass.m

```
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AppOfTheDay"];
       [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"WDJpxs4PzH"
        block:^(PFObject *comment, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
                PFFile *post = [comment objectForKey:@"PhotoName"];
                PFFile *post2 = [comment objectForKey:@"logo"];
                PFFile *post3 = [comment objectForKey:@"similar1"];
               PFFile *post4 = [comment objectForKey:@"similar2"];
               imageasy=[[AsyncImageView alloc] init];
               imageasy1=[[AsyncImageView alloc] init];
               imageasy2=[[AsyncImageView alloc] init];
               imageasy3=[[AsyncImageView alloc] init];
               [imageasy setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[post url]]];
                [imageasy1 setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[post2 url]]];
               [imageasy2 setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[post3 url]]];
              [imageasy3 setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[post4 url]]];
       }];
```

Comment: i am going to try this.

Comment: i am seeing this for the first time AsyncImageView *imageasy=[[AsyncImageView alloc] init];I have outlets for my imageviews.i dont know how to use them here?

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView you can download the AsyncImageView.h and .m classes into your project ,it is usefull to reduce the loading of the image,and instead of uiimageview you can this,for example :-AsyncImageView *imageasy3=[[AsyncImageView alloc] init]; genrally if yoou create uiimageview  you will alloc like this UIImageView *imageasy3=[[UIImageView alloc] init];

Comment: Actually i have four imageviews on the homescreen of my app.how will this load the required images to my imageviews?